# Spark JDBC with HIVE - Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a sample table(stuends1) in HIVE which I want to connect from Spark using JDBC (as Hive is in AWS, not in same cluster). I was just trying with following code

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").newInstance()
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME").setMaster("local[*]")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .getOrCreate()

val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://34.223.237.55:10000")
  .option("dbtable", "students1")
  .option("user", "hduser")
  .option("password", "hadoop")
  //.option("driver", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
  .load()

println("able to connect------------------")

jdbcDF.show

jdbcDF.printSchema()

jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("std")



val sqlDF = spark.sql("select * from std")

println("Start println-----")
spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from std").collect().foreach(println)
println("end println-----")
sqlDF.show(false)
}
```

I tried in multiple ways but all the time its showing table structure with column name only. Like ...

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|students1.name|students1.age|students1.gpa|
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But not data, but able to get data when trying to with dbeaver from my local with SQL query. From spark,  jdbcDF.printSchema() also showing proper schema , so I guess no issue with connection.

I am using spark 2.1.1 with HIVE 1.2.1. My sbt.build file is like this ....

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

"log4j"  %   "log4j"  % "1.2.17",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11"                        % "2.1.1" ,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10"             % "1.6.2",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10"   % "2.0.0-preview",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11"                         % "2.1.1" ,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10"                        % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.hive"  % "hive-jdbc"                              % "1.2.1"
```

)

can any one suggest why I am not getting any output of show(). Thanks in advance...

Comment: could you post the output of `jdbcDF.count()`?

Comment: strange !!! count is 0... that means no data picked up... but select * from students1 ,from dbeaver showing all data. I must did something wrong.....

Comment: What is table format of your hive table is it ORC ?

Comment: no , its text format.

Comment: Why not configure spark to point to the AWS metastore?

Comment: @summerbulb , is it possible for spark installation which is not in the cluster ?

Comment: please post result of same steps from spark-shell. I am curios is your spark app requires some additional hive configs.

Comment: Yes. Configure <property> <name>hive.metastore.uris</name> <value>thrift://<n.n.n.n>:9083</value> <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description> </property> 
 In hive-core.xml

Comment: @FaigB, I did that , but same output....

Comment: If you have partitions, try running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE ${tablename}`

Comment: after using MSCK REPAIR TABLE ${tablename} also same output

Comment: why are you trying with jdbc, why not simple with Hive ?

Comment: @dumitru, as spark system is not a part of my hadoop cluster

Comment: I tried with same spark code with postgres SQL and mysql , in both it worked properly, I guess some issue with HIVE jdbc driver....

Answer (score 2):

Please mention fetchsize property, It will solve the issue of no data.

fetchsize - The JDBC fetch size, which determines how many rows to fetch per round trip. This can help to gain some performance for JDBC drivers which has low fetch size (eg. Oracle with 10 rows). This option applies only for reading.

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://34.223.237.55:10000")
  .option("dbtable", "students1")
  .option("user", "hduser")
  .option("password", "hadoop")
  .option("fetchsize", "20")
  .load()
```